# Population-biology, migration-patterns, & ethology of the Big Five (elephants, rhinos, lions, leopards, & buffalo) in S. Africa's winter months?

Tags: ethology, population-biology, feline, migration, biogeography

I know that animals are unpredictable, but I also know that there are seasons in which the wildlife are more active. Now, August in South Africa is still their winter season, which is emerging into spring, and I was wondering what the population-biology, migration-patterns, and ethology of the Big Five (black rhinoceros, African elephant, water buffalo, African lion, African leopard) are like in August?

Now that's quite a variety of animals (some migrate, and others don't), but I'm essentially wondering: **are the wildlife less active in August (because it's winter) or do they stay pretty active all-year round, even in the winter months (because of the warmer climate)?** *Are the migratory animals present in the winter time in Kruger National Park?*